# How to run a program in git-bash.exe in a new window

Tags: windows, bash, git

When I run the program `/c/Users/PetrKrysl/AppData/Local/Julia-1.0.1/bin/julia.exe` in an open `git-bash.exe` window, it runs fine. 
However, I'm not able to start a new window with

```
git-bash.exe /c/Users/PetrKrysl/AppData/Local/Julia-1.0.1/bin/julia.exe
```

A window opens, but doesn't stay open.
There is some sort of error message,
but the window vanishes too quickly for me to read what happened.

Comment: Use this option `--hold always` with `git-bash.exe` command. If you find any error add that in your question.

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't work. The window still closed immediately. (I used this as  git-bash.exe --hold always /c/Users/PetrKrysl/AppData/Local/Julia-1.0.1/bin/julia.exe. I hope that was what you intended?)

Comment: The capture a video and play it slowly.

Comment: Excellent idea! The error message is bash: /c/Users/PetrKrysl/AppData/Local/Julia-1.0.1/bin/julia.exe: cannot execute binary file

Comment: If `git-bash.exe` is compatible with `bash` you will need `git-bash.exe -c /c/Users/PetrKrysl/AppData/Local/Julia-1.0.1/bin/julia.exe`. Omitting the `-c` causes the file parameter to be interpreted as a text file containing `bash` commands, and a binary file is not allowed, as you observed..

Comment: Fantastic, that was it! Thank you very much indeed. Petr

Comment: I have submitted an answer, so that others can see that it is solved, provided that you accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `git-bash.exe` is compatible with `bash` you will need:

```
git-bash.exe -c /c/Users/PetrKrysl/AppData/Local/Julia-1.0.1/bin/julia.exe
```

Omitting the `-c` causes the file parameter to be interpreted as a text file containing `bash` commands, and a binary file is not allowed, as you observed.

The same error is generated if you try to execute a binary program with the `source` or `.` command from a running `bash`.